# How to retrieve data returned by intercepting an observable

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I have an Angular 6 cli application. I have a component that uses a service to retrieve data. I am introducing an ngrx store to my application.
What I like to do is to have the service abstract the store interactions.

First of all, is this a good idea?
If so, here comes the question. All the code snippets only show the relevant code.

What I have is a utility function that makes the http calls.

```
public get(route: string, params: any): Observable<any>{
   return this.http.get(url, {headers: httpHeaders})
   .pipe(
      map(response =>{
         return response;
      })
   );
}
```

the service uses the above function

```
public getData(url: string, params: any): Observable<any> {
   return this.fhirDataRetrievalBroker.get(url, params);
}
```

What I like to do is to add the data retrieved in the above code to the ngrx store.

How should I change the code to achieve that?

Comment: FWIW, your call to `map()` is currently useless.

Comment: agreed, left over from some massaging of the response.

Answer (score 0):

The way I changed the code was to pass an additional interface to the service itself to dispatch the update to the store.